# Asp.net login control redirect to itself

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I have a problem with Login Control in asp.net. when I entered the correct password, the login.aspx redirect to itself. why? I want to goto Nazarat.aspx after successful login.(Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fNazarat.aspx)

web.config inside the parent folder of nazarat.aspx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
          <authorization>    
        <allow roles="Admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

and in my login.aspx:

```
 <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
            RenderOuterTable="false"  >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                ....
....
....

            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
```

Comment: post your code so that we can identify what actually the problem you're getting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the User you are using to login a member of the Role: Admin ?
As per the settings:

```
<allow roles="Admin" />
<deny users="*" />
```

Any User who is a Admin will be allowed, All other users will be denied access.

May be you may want to use: ? instead of * as in:

```
<allow roles="Admin" />
<deny users="?" />
```

Comment: I used this but all users can login.

Comment: Show your web.config settings for <authentication> tag

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"  />
    </authentication>

Comment: All seems fine to me. The login control has a 'MembershipProvider' attribute.  Did you set it properly ? Also check for any possible issues with Cookies .

Comment: In case you don't use Membership provider , check your own event handlers created for Authenticate event etc..

Comment: Thanks,It worked, The problem was I not add users to specific role.